# Twitter Feed Manual Refresh Button

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, javascript

trying to get my twitter feed to refresh, through a link/button/whatever. For some reason it's not working, might be due to functions in my .js file being ordered wrong but I'm completely stumped and need some expert advice!

The test page is at [This Page](http://carnivalrag.com/bootstrap/twitter/)

The .js file:

```
function closeStuff(){

    jQuery('#tweet_container').fadeOut(1000,function(){$('#tweet_container').empty();});
    jQuery('#photosContainer div').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    }

function refreshStuff(user)
{

    jQuery('#tweet_container').empty();
    loadTweets(user);

}


function loadTweets(user){
  // Declare variables to hold twitter API url and user name
  var twitter_api_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json';

  // Enable caching
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });

  // Send JSON request
  // The returned JSON object will have a property called "results" where we find
  // a list of the tweets matching our request query
  $.getJSON(
    twitter_api_url + '?callback=?&rpp=10&q=from:' + user,
    function(data) {
      $.each(data.results, function(i, tweet) {
        // Uncomment line below to show tweet data in Fire Bug console
        // Very helpful to find out what is available in the tweet objects
        //console.log(tweet);

        // Before we continue we check that we got data
        if(tweet.text !== undefined) {
          // Calculate how many hours ago was the tweet posted
          var date_tweet = new Date(tweet.created_at);
          var date_now   = new Date();
          var date_diff  = date_now - date_tweet;
          var hours      = Math.round(date_diff/(1000*60*60));

          // Build the html string for the current tweet
          var tweet_html = '<div class="tweet_text">';
          tweet_html    += '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/';
          tweet_html    += user + '/status/' + tweet.id_str + '" target="_blank">';
          tweet_html    += tweet.text + '<\/a><\/div>';
          tweet_html    += '<div class="tweet_hours">' + hours;
          tweet_html    += ' hours ago<\/div>';

          // Append html string to tweet_container div
          $('#tweet_container').hide().append(tweet_html).fadeIn(1000);
        }

      });
    }

  );

  $('#tweet_container').hide().append('<a href="#" class="refresh" onClick="refreshStuff(user);">Refresh</a>').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
  $('#tweet_container').hide().append('<a href="#" class="close" onClick="closeStuff();">Back</a>').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);

}




function clickPhoto(id){


var user;

switch(id)
{
case 1: user='cantqwontq';break;
case 2: user='carnivalrag';break;
case 3: user='samdlc';break;

default: user='0';break;
}



//jQuery('#tweet_container').empty();

jQuery('#photosContainer div').fadeOut();


loadTweets(user);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open webconsole(ctrl+shift+k) in firefox and press the Refresh link/button you will see the error "user is not defined"

I think problem is here

```
<a class="refresh" onclick="refreshStuff(user);" href="#">Refresh</a>
```

when appending try user.toString();

try {{{

```
    "$('#tweet_container').hide().append('<a href="#" class="refresh" onClick="refreshStuff(
'user.toString()');">Refresh</a>').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

}}}

Cheers :)

Comment: Doesn't want to work :( getting Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined

Comment: sorry try '"+user.toString()+"' also add quotes

Comment: Almost works, but now I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: cantqwontq is not defined

Comment: For some reason, if the username is a number, it has no problem